# How to select a text using javascript so that it is copied in the X-mouse clipboard?

Tags: javascript, x11, xorg

On X11's Windows Manager, you can select a text and paste it using the middle mouse button.

This is really convenient.

Also with javascript you can select the text on input focus.

```
<input type="text" onFocus="select();" value="The value">
```

Is it possible that this select function also set the selection in the Mouse Clipboard as if it was selected by hand ?

Comment: you want to paste it out of the browser scope?

Comment: You don't have access to the users clipboard! There are plugins like ZeroClipBoard available, that uses Flash.

Comment: I'd be extremely wary of trying to make a web page implement a particular UI's conventions for copy/paste. If the user is running a browser in X Windows then they'll have that automatically. If they are using Microsoft Windows or another desktop then they won't expect selecting text to copy it so you shouldn't violate the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: I don't want to violate any principle I just want a basic feature of my OS to work with the javascript `select()` function.

Answer (score 0):

ZeroClipBoard is definitely the way to go with this.

[ZeroClipboard](http://jonrohan.github.com/ZeroClipboard/) or [zclip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/)

Comment: ZeroClipboard copy it in your clipboard but not in your mouse clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found on client side is to [run autocutsel](https://superuser.com/a/177541/13818).

```
$ autocutsel & autocutsel -s PRIMARY &
```

But this is not exactly what I want.